# Using AJAX how to go about editing a value in the database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, foreach

Hi guys so I have used ajax within my PHP file to delete an entry which is inside a table, this is my code for that:

```
<?php foreach (get_all_categories() as $r) { ?>

<td>
      <?php
            echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  delete delete-action"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> Delete</a></button> 
                                    <input type="hidden" value="'. $r['category_id'] .'"  name="delete[]">';
      ?>
</td>

<?php } ?>


//AJAX CALL

var id;
$('button.delete-category').click(function(e) {
id = $(this).parent()[0].childNodes[3].value;
  swal({
title: "Are you sure?",
text: " You will not be able to undo this action !",
type: "warning",
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
closeOnConfirm: false,
html: false
}, function(){
$.post( "delete_category.php", { deletecategoryfunction: id}, function( data ) {
location.reload();
});
});
});
```

However my question is if I had an edit button, how would I be able to go about doing the edit using AJAX, I been stuck on this for the past few days and that is the reason for asking this question on here.

$r basically pulls list of all the items in a table that I have called category which contains (category name, description and availability.) So when I do this edit button is there anyway I could go about doing it so that I can change or modify category name, description and availability for category table.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you really want to add web 2.0 interactivity, you should never write "location.reload()". With JQuery you could simply remove the row of the table (why are you using columns instead??).
In your question it is not clear what you'd like to edit. But in general you'd just send to the server the new value of whatever (maybe, you want to edit category names?) with its id. For editing you might use , and to get value of the input you'd use $(element).val().

Comment: So how else do I go about refreshing the page ? because I am doing the edit and it works fine now, but when since I have the location.reload(); , it just reloads the page soon as click on the edit button, Would I be able to redirect the user from the php file when I do ajax call ?

Comment: @jomin_george94, basically this is how your page should work:
there is a script on the server that renders your page ONCE,
there is client-side javascript that allows to modify for interactions with the page and sending data back to server,
there is a server-side script that ONLY handles ajax requests. 

So there is no need to refresh the page, and you shouldn't do this as it breaks user experience.